# GrantedAuthority caused JSON mapping exception

Tags: java, json, spring

Faced this

> Could not write JSON: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.springboot.model.User["authorities"])

error while trying to pass list of users to my html page.

I suppose the key is in wrong serialization of Role class, but i have no idea how to solve this problem.

Both classes are below. 
User and Role class are connected with ManytoMany model.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_for_spring_crud")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class User implements UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "role_id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "role")
private String roleName;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
@JsonIgnore
List<User> users;
```

And a method in the Controller class, if needed.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/admin", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public List<User> showUsersTable(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
List<User> listUsers = userService.listUsers();
return listUsers;
```

Thought about writing custom serializer, but cant figure how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The key, as always, is in paying attention to your own classes, and especcially to overriding methods

The correct version of getAuthorities() method solved the problem

```
@Override
public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
     List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role: roles) {
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
        role.getPrivileges().stream()
        .map(p -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(p.getRoleName()))
        .forEach(grantedAuthorities::add);
    }
    return grantedAuthorities;
}
```

Thanks for your attention.